# CSS 2nd level submenus appearing in 1st level submenu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

So I've had to recode a webpage from scratch because the one I inherited was making W3C's Validator cry.  So now I have a nice XHTML1.1 page that validates fine (and wonderfully javascript free!), but for some reason my menu isn't displaying correctly.  The main level is fine, displays in a nice bar.  The 1st submenu is fine, displaying in nice hanging lists.  But the 2nd submenus, which should be appearing to the right of the 1st submenu when their parents are selected are instead appearing in the 1st submenu with the parents.  I've been fiddling with this but have been unable to find a solution (here or elsewhere) that corrects this.  The problem areas are under "General Info->Government Pubs/Forms" where "DA Pam 25-30" appears under "Government Pubs/Forms" instead of as a submenu "Goverment Pubs/Forms" and under "Other Info->Useful Links" where "DISA WebMail", "AKO", and "JTDI" should all be a submenu of "Useful Links" instead of listed under it.

Thank you for your assistance.

Code for the page is as follows:

```
C:\Users\user.3087689\amaya\1\internalsite.html<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <title>Internal Site</title>
 <meta name="generator" content="Amaya, see http://www.w3.org/Amaya/" />
 <style type="text/css">
  body {background-color:#000000}
  ul {list-style: none;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;}
  ul li {display: block;position: relative;float: left;border:1px solid #8f8f8f}
  li ul {display: none;}
  ul li a {display: block;background: #8f8f8f;padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;text-decoration: none; white-space: nowrap;color: #000000;}
  ul li a:hover {background: #6666ff;}
  li:hover ul {display: block; position: absolute;}
  li:hover li {float: none;}
  li:hover a {background: #8f8f8f;}
  li:hover li a:hover {background: #6666ff;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<p><img alt="Hey, a logo!" src="logo.jpg"
style="display: block; text-align: center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto"
width="457" height="327" /> </p>

<p style="text-align:center;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"><span
style="font-family: Arial"><span style="font-size: 16pt"><span
style="color: #FFFFFF">All SOPs are now maintained on
QT9</span></span></span></p>
<ul id="drop-nav">
  <li><a href="#">General Info<br />
    </a> 
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://hazard.com/msds/">MSDS Lookup</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Government
        Pubs/Forms</a> 
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://www.google.com">DA Pam 25-30</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Corporate Web<br />
    </a> 
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://www.google.com" title="TLS">DI TLS</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.google.com" title="DI WebMail">DI
      WebMail</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.google.com">DI Learn</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.google.com">My Journey</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.google.com">QT9</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Ethics
        Point</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">PC/Admin<br />
    </a> 
    <ul>
      <li><a href="www.google.com">BackShops</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Quality Control</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Mechanics</a> 
    <ul>
      <li><a href="www.google.com">Termination Chart</a></li>
      <li><a href="www.google.com">Drill Bit Size Chart</a></li>
      <li><a href="www.google.com">Rivet Standards</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Supply</a> 
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.google.com">ULLS-A Supply</a></li>
      <li><a href="www.google.com">WebFLIS</a></li>
      <li><a href="www.google.com">LIW</a></li>
      <li><a href="www.google.com">ArmyProperty.com</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Other Info</a> 
    <ul>
      <li><a href="www.google.com">Julian Calendar</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Useful Links</a> 
        <ul>
          <li><a href="www.google.com">DISA Webmail</a></li>
          <li><a href="www.google.com">AKO</a></li>
          <li><a href="www.google.com">JTDI</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" title="Corporate VPN Sites">Web Directory</a> 
    <ul>
      <li><a href="www.google.com">Contract Main</a></li>
      <li><a href="www.google.com">Corporate Intranet</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<p style="text-align:right;margin-left:auto;margin-right:0;"><a
href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer"><img
src="http://www.w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml11" alt="Valid XHTML 1.1" height="31"
width="88" /></a> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Additional information: I'm coding in Amaya and testing in Firefox 25.0.1.  I don't need an external stylesheet because this is an internal site with only a single page.  Javascript is not a valid solution.  I have changed most of the links to point to Google for testing purposes, and you don't need any imgs to troubleshoot this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, display: block hides the submenus on all levels initially, but the current css then says to show them on li:hover --- edit the line that hides the uls to this:

li ul, li:hover ul ul {display: none;}

That hides the third level even when displaying the second.

Then you want to add some left margin maybe to the third level -- however wide the second level is.

On another note, I've often used the Son of Suckerfish method -- it's really lightweight, and you don't have to use the extra javascript if you don't care about supporting old browsers that don't support the :hover psuedoclass http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/

Comment: Well, that moved the 2nd submenu elements, but also prevents them from displaying at all, so unfortunately that didn't help very much.

Comment: You just have to tell them to show, by adding this to the correct line: li:hover ul, li li:hover ul { display: block; }

Comment: Well, that's certainly better, if not quite what I was looking for.  The 2nd submenu is now hidden until mousing over their parent in the 1st submenu.  They display immediately below their parent on mouseover.  Is there a way to cause them to appear to the right of their parent instead?

Comment: Yeah, with margin. So if you second level menu is 10em wide and each li is 1em high, then this will put your third level menu in the right place: li ul ul { margin: -1em 0 0 10em; }

Comment: Well, still not great, but functional.  Think I'll give the script-less version of your suggestion a try.  Was trying to avoid having that much stuff in the page, but it's looking like that can't be done and still achieve the desired effect.  Thanks for your help.